# Não consigo programar um botão do jFrame

Tags: netbeans

Toda a vez que dou um duplo clique no botão para abrir o ActionPerformed dele, o NETbeans cria ele no meio de outro ActionPerformade de outro botão.
Código inical:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if(jTable.getSelectedRow()>-1){
    jComboBox1.removeAllItems();
    suamae.forEach((nana) -> {
        jComboBox1.addItem(nana);
    });

    
   String[] isso = new String[4];
   for(int sim =0; sim<4;sim++){
   isso[sim]=jTable.getValueAt(jTable.getSelectedRow(),sim).toString();
   
   }
   jTextField1.setText(isso[0]);
   jComboBox2.setSelectedItem(isso[1]);
   jComboBox1.setSelectedItem(isso[2]);
   
   jPanel1.setVisible(true);
          
}                                        
else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Você não cadastrou animais");
    }}
```

Após dar duplo-clique sobre o novo botão para alterar seu código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if(jTable.getSelectedRow()>-1){
    jComboBox1.removeAllItems();
    suamae.forEach((nana) -> {
        jComboBox1.addItem(nana);
    });

    
   String[] isso = new String[4];
   for(int sim =0; sim<4;sim++){
   isso[sim]=jTable.getValueAt(jTable.getSelectedRow(),sim).toString();
   
   }
   jTextField1.setText(isso[0]);
   jComboBox2.setSelectedItem(isso[1]);
   jComboBox1.setSelectedItem(isso[2]);
   
   jPanel1.setVisible(true);
          
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        
else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Você não cadastrou animais");
    }}
```

já tentei trocar o nome do botão, reiniciar o netbeans, tirar o Else e voltar ele pro lugar, porem nada da certo.
Todo o código da erro após fazer isso.

Alguém sabe o que posso fazer?

Não liguem pro nome das variáveis kkkkk

Comment: Nao adicione codigo em forma de imagem, edite a pergunta e adicione de forma textual,  na forma de um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel executar.

Comment: Editado! Coloquei o trecho do código que da erro

Comment: Cara isso parece ser defeito, reinstala a ide e ve se resolve